# Simplifying Roots and Trigonometric Identities

Tags: sympy

I have a bunch of sympy expressions similar to

```
g = sp.sympify('2**(1/4) * 5**(1/2) * 3**(3/4) * 6**(-1)')
```

which I want to simplify. In this case, I would very much prefer this rewritten as (25/24)**(1/4), but I couldn't find settings for simplify or the other methods [listed here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#) that would let me do this.

So what I want is given a bunch of natural numbers *a_i* and rational exponents *(p_i/q_i)*, I want the product

```
a1**(p1/q1) * a2**(p2/q2) * ... * ak**(pk/qk)
```

to be rewritten as

```
(r/s)**(1/lcm(q1,q2,...,qk))
```

or possibly

```
(r1**s1 * r2**s2 *... rm**sm)**(1/lcm(q1,q2,...,qk))
```

where the *r_i* are the prime factors and the *s_i* are integers. Do any of the built in functions allow me to do that?

**Secondly**, I noted that Sympy won't simplify certain trigonometric identities. For example it doesn't seem to know that

```
tan((1/2)*atan(x)) = (sqrt(x**2 + 1)-1)/x
```

How can I tell Sympy to use this identity, even if x is a much more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def simplify_root(g):
    d = sp.degree(sp.minimal_polynomial(g))
    return sp.Pow(sp.simplify(g**d), sp.Rational(1, d), evaluate=False)
```